# My Button is not working to get next activity by clicking on them

Tags: java, android

I implemented Bottom navigation bar in my project. When I declare and initialize buttons and then set onClickListener for them. The onclicklistener is not working fine without any error in logcat. I think its logical mistake that I'm unable to understand please see the code and guide me. (If you think the question is not according to community standards  then I'm sorry in advance because I'm a beginner in java)

I searched a lot of questions related to this but nothing works for me.

Here is my main activity:

```
 public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the device
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }
   }

     private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_notifications:
                        selectedFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                        break;
                }

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
        };
  }
```

Here is my First Fragment named HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnFertilizers;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    btnFertilizers = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnFertilizers);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    btnFertilizers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Fertilizers.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat shows zero error.
I believe that here is the problem area. This is because the click function is not working properly for Fertilizers.class:

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    btnFertilizers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Fertilizers.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my FragmentHome.xml :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/agriculture_home">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/e_agriculture_logo"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="E-Agriculture"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="29sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/fertilizers"
                                android:layout_width="144dp"
                                android:layout_height="113dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/fertilizers_png" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/fertilizers"
                                android:text="Fertilizers"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                                />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btnFertilizers"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/seeds"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/seed" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/seeds"
                                android:text="Seeds"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btn_seeds"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/deseases"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/deseases" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/deseases"
                                android:text="Diseases"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btn_deseases"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageViewPesticides"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/pesticides" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPesticides"
                                android:text="Pesticides"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btnPesticides"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageViewWeatherForecast"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/weatherforecast" />

                            <TextView
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewWeatherForecast"
                                android:text="Weather Forecast"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btnWeatherForecast"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageViewArticles"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/video" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewArticles"
                                android:text="Videos"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btnArticles"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageViewFeedback"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/feedback" />

                            <TextView
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewFeedback"
                                android:text="Feedback"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btnFeedback"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageViewLocation"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/location_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLocation"
                                android:text="Location"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/btnLocation"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.xml file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:background="@color/colorGreen"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

How I should setOnClickListener to access my wanted activity?

Comment: In your HomeFragment, you are implementing `View.OnClick` interface, but in its method, you are not differentiating the views. Implement an if-else(or a switch depending on view counts) and check `if (view.getId() == R.id.yourView)`. If it matches then start the activity.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad can you write please its correct format in the block of code, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling another onClick lisnter inside the onclick method so it will no work.You should have to change the code like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

     if (view.getId() == R.id.btnFertilizers) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Fertilizers.class);
       getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}
```

Return v in your onCreateViewMethod .

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

btnFertilizers = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnFertilizers);

return v;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for Sincere Attention.I implements your Suggestion but problem is still existing

Comment: can u find any solution?

Comment: Yes.Return v in your onCreatView method.

Answer (score 0):

Move this code into `onCreateView`.

```
btnFertilizers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Fertilizers.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

remove this

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```

remove this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) { }
```